# Vertical space in TOC (references entry)

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

The references entry has a vertical space in the TOC page, something like that

[image: That's the output]

How could I remove this space and make the references section just like a chapter in the TOC??
I'm using the memoir classes and have tried  everything to solve this problem.

Edit: Here a MWE

```
 \documentclass[
    % -- opções da classe memoir --
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
    openright,          % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
    oneside,            % para impressão em verso e anverso. Oposto a oneside
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
    % -- opções da classe abntex2 -
    sumario=tradicional, % o padrão é sumario=abnt-6027-2012
    chapter=TITLE,      % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    section=title,      % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    subsection=title,   % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsubsection=TITLE,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    % -- opções do pacote babel --
    english,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    french,             % idioma adicional para hifenização
    spanish,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    brazil,             % o último idioma é o principal do documento
    ]{abntex2}


\usepackage{cmap}               % Mapear caracteres especiais no PDF
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
\usepackage{lastpage}           % Usado pela Ficha catalográfica
\usepackage{indentfirst}        % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção.
\usepackage{color}              % Controle das cores
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tocloft}


%%Alteração da fonte para helvetica (onde originou a Arial)
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

%
% ---

\DisemulatePackage{tocbibind}
\let\bibsection\relax
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot,numbib]{tocbibind}




% ---
% Pacotes adicionais, usados apenas no âmbito do Modelo Canônico do abnteX2
% ---
\usepackage{lipsum}             % para geração de dummy text
% ---

% ---
% Pacotes de citações
% ---
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}     % Paginas com as citações na bibl
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   % Citações padrão ABNT, alf=nome do autor, num=numerica
\citeoption{abnt-etal-list=3} % o comando "abnt-etal-list=0" faz com que o et-al para quando tem mais de 3 autores não apareça e todos os autores aparecam abreviadodos, pag13 do manual do bibtex

\titulo{TITLE}
\autor{AUTHOR}
\local{VR}
\data{2014}
\orientador{DR COOPER}
%\coorientador{Equipe \abnTeX}
\instituicao{%
        OSW
        \par
        CEN
        \par
        ELECTRICAL ENG.
        \par
        FINAL}
\tipotrabalho{FINAL}
\preambulo{TEXT FINAL}
% ---


% ---
% Configurações de aparência do PDF final

% alterando o aspecto da cor azul
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{41,5,195}

% informações do PDF
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
        %pagebackref=true,
        pdftitle={\@title}, 
        pdfauthor={\@author},
        pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo},
        pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
        pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{trabalho acadêmico}, 
        colorlinks=true,            % false: boxed links; true: colored links
        linkcolor=blue,             % color of internal links
        citecolor=blue,             % color of links to bibliography
        filecolor=magenta,              % color of file links
        urlcolor=blue,
        bookmarksdepth=4
}
\makeatother
% --- 

% ---
% compila o indice
% ---
\makeindex
% ---


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% ATENCAO, DENTRO DO ARQUIVO CONFIGURACOES.STY ESTA TODA A PARTE DE FORMATAÇÃO PARA PESQUISA
%\usepackage{configuracoes}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% ----
% Início do documento
% ----
\begin{document}

% Retira espaço extra obsoleto entre as frases.
\frenchspacing 

% ----------------------------------------------------------
% ELEMENTOS PRÉ-TEXTUAIS
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\pretextual

% ---
% Capa
% ---
\imprimircapa
% ---


\imprimirfolhaderosto*


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\bfseries REFERENCES}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep} %DOTS
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage
% ---

% ---
% inserir lista de tabelas
% ---
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\bfseries TABLES}
%\pdfbookmark[0]{\listtablename}{lot}
\listoftables*
\cleardoublepage
% ---

% ---
% inserir lista de ilustrações
% ---
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\bfseries FIGURES}
%\pdfbookmark[0]{\listfigurename}{lof}
\listoffigures*
\cleardoublepage
% ---


\textual
\pagestyle{simple}


\chapter{CHAPTER 1}{\label{intro}}

\chapter{CHAPTER 2}


\chapter{CHAPTER 3}

\chapter{CHAPTER 4}


\chapter{CHAPTER 5}

\chapter{CHAPTER 6}
\begin{itemize}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
\end{itemize}

\chapter{CHAPTER 7}


\chapter{CHAPTER 8}



\cite{balanco}
\cite{projecao}

\chapter{CHAPTER 1}

\cite{evolucao}

\section{Final}
\cite{cabine}

\chapter{COM}
\cite{trafoweg}

\cite{disjuntoralta}

\chapter{CONCLUSÃO}
teste


\postextual


\renewcommand{\bibname}{\textbf{References}}
\bibliography{abntex2-modelo-references}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Please post a Minimal Working Example of code which people can compile to reproduce the problem.

Comment: So... Could someone help me?

Comment: Posting a `.rar` archive is not a great way to explain your question or to attract help. Please take a look at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx to learn how to ask a good question on this site. Note especially the linked guidance on creating a suitable MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possibility 1:

The easiest way would be to remove the `\postextual` in front of the bibliography.

```
%\postextual

\renewcommand{\bibname}{\textbf{References}}
\bibliography{abntex2-modelo-references}
```

### Possibility 2:

In case you need the `\postextual` in front of the bibliography for some reason, you can hack the spacing of the `toc` by inserting `\addtocontents{toc}{...}`. However notice that I just guessed the `28pt`, you might have to adjust this value to get a perfect output.

```
\postextual

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-28pt}}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\textbf{References}}
\bibliography{abntex2-modelo-references}
```

[image]